# Монтирование директорий docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose

Я запускаю `compose` из директории `/home/user/compose-demo`. В директории `/home/user/settings` хранятся настройки для приложения из контейнера. Можно ли составить `volumes yaml` так, чтобы вместо директории `/usr/share/config` внутри контейнера использовалась внешняя директория с моей машины `/home/user/settings` и как это сделать?

Comment: приведи пример своего docker-compose чтобы можно было посмотреть что именно ты имеешь и что хочешь получить в итоге